# Camel 2.x not recognising 'preSort' File component parameter

Tags: sorting, apache-camel, camel-file

We're using Camel's File component to receive files that are placed into a directory. The URI for this is similar to:

```
file:///some/directory/inbox?delay=30000&delete=true&include=DSINV.*%5C.OUT&preSort=true&readLock=changed&readLockCheckInterval=5000&readLockMinLength=0
```

previously we did not have the 'preSort=true' parameter, and files were being received in a random order.

We added this parameter, but we are now getting the following error in the logs:

```
There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint.
Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. 
Unknown parameters=[\{preSort=true}]
```

The version of Camel we are using is 2.15.4. The [documentation for the 2.x version of the File component](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/file-component.html) states that this is a valid parameter.

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps it needs to be upgraded to the latest?

Comment: @jspcal unfortunately that's not going to happen any time soon as it would require us upgrading the version of Java we are currently using (ver 8)

Answer (score 0):

This has been added in 2.21.0
https://camel.apache.org/releases/release-2.21.0/
See the related jira here
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11656

So it is not available in 2.15.4 you have to at least update to 2.21.0 in order to work.

I don't know about the latest but is seems even the most resent Camel versions  still support java 8

https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/index.html#_jdk_requirements

Camel 2.x supports JDK 8

Camel 3.0 - 3.4 supports JDK 8 and 11

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Good to know what version the 'preSort' was added. Unfortunately this is a running installation at a customer site, so upgrading right now doesn't suit. But we will look at upgrading soon. In the meantime we'll just need to stick with the 'sortBy=file:name' which doesn't seem to be working.